# Installing ADB drivers / Getting Windows 8.1 laptop to recognise Oneplus One

Tags: android, adb, windows-8.1

I'm having great difficulty trying to get my laptop (running Win 8.1) to recognise my Oneplus One. So it's not shown as a device in My Computer' although it does appear as a device in Device Manager (albeit this is under 'Other Devices', and gives the following error: 'The drivers for this device are not installed. (Code 28)').

I have tried installing ADB drivers from various places: Samsung drivers, Universal ADB drivers, Google USB drivers etc, but all to no avail.

The Samsung drivers appear to install fine, and there are no errors when I 'update the driver software' with these drivers, although even after restarting etc, it doesn't make the device show up under My Computer (so I can back up the phone then root it.)

With the Universal and Google drivers, when I try to select their folder location during the 'update the driver software' process, it throws up the error: 'Windows could not find driver software for your device'.

I have even tried disabling Driver Signature Enforcement, but this didn't help either.

Frankly, I have been stumped and other posts on similar issues have not provided a solution to my problem!

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you selected Mass Storage for USB Connectivity Settings while connecting?

Comment: I have tried the above in both MTP and PTP connectivity!

Comment: try my way of making the "truly universal" driver http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-make-truly-universal-adb-and.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  I found that I had to install the latest Microsoft MTP drivers and then found that my USB 3.0 driver was from the wrong company.  I checked my book for the motherboard and it said the USB hardware was for x company. The manufacturer of the motherboard had a web site that was having me download the wrong USB drivers. So, I went to the x company that was in my MOBO book and they had drivers to download. Problem solved. Also you have to select I'll find the divers not let Microsoft find them. Here's a web site that has the correct procedure. http://www.howtogeek.com/195607/how-to-get-your-android-device-to-show-up-in-file-explorer-if-it-isnt/?PageSpeed=noscript

Answer (score 0):

I also cannot get my phone to show up in MTP and PTP mode under Windows 8.1.
BUT, I discovered that if I plug the phone to the computer, then restart in Recovery mode (TWRP for example), then the MTP device shows up.